# Access token on URL as a query param in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a app that sends emails which contains GMail Action Buttons.  For these Action Buttons, I need to send an access token on the URL itself. ( See https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/limited-use-access-tokens ) This access token should be a one time token. 
How can I generate such a token and implement an API endpoint to check for the token in query params and authorize the action?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you want to send url as `http://example.com/xyz` and attach access token to it, let's say `access_token`. So complete URL will be `http://example.com/xyz/someRandomToken`.

You need to register a route say,

```
Route::get('xyz/{token}','yourController@yourMethod')->name('url-to-send');

//Which you can access in your method as below

public function yourMethod($accessToken){
    echo $accessToken;
}
```

So now to generate URL you can use as below,

```
$url = route('url-to-send',['yourRandomToken']);
// http://example.com/xyz/yourRandomToken
```

---

So now to validate this,

Step 1 - Create table say `access_tokens` to store `token` and `user_id` if required.

Step 2 - Create `token` add to `table` and use same token to attach to url.

Step 3 - When user click's the **action button**, method `yourMethod` will be executed and you will get sent `yourRandomToken` back, which you will validate in database. If `yourRandomToken` exist then just delete the token as it is for one time use.

Hope it helps you. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, My question is about generating the token and using Passport API authentication for authorizing the token. I know how to use path params and query params.

Comment: Ok. You didn't mentioned anything about passport earlier.

Comment: Use `hash('sha256', time())` to create a token, because `Hash::make(time())` gives 404.